# Installing Android Studio Application

Tags: environment-variables

how to add android-studio/bin/ to my PATH environmental variable?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have installed Android studio like this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Now `sudo vi /etc/environment`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/gradle/bin"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export JAVA_HOME
GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle-2.10
export GRADLE_HOME
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python
```

Go to the last entry on the PATH(1st line) just before the double quotes
and then add `:<Path of android studio>` before double quotes

```
source /etc/environment
```

Now verify by doing

```
echo $PATH
```

you should be able to invoke Android studio from any where now.

As this is an IDE - better to create .desktop for it under /usr/share/applications. I have one for Eclipse IDE

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/usr/share/applications# cat eclipse.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 4
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
```

You can also create something like that.